# How to build a maven project in a docker container efficiently?

Tags: java, maven, docker, build

I am trying to improve the build process by reducing it's duration. The build is done in a docker container based on the [official maven docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/maven?tab=description).

The way I am doing it right now works well, but doesn't preserve the local maven repository for subsequent builds, which means that all downloads need to happen again for every build.

Let's focus on what I actually tried to improve that.
I tried the following steps:
1. create a docker volume for maven's .m2 directory
2. build a custom maven image (contains custom maven settings)
3. run a docker container based on that image, mounting the volume from step 1 and bind mount the maven project (the directory that contains the top level pom-file)

Here is the dockerfile for the custom maven docker image:

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-11

# Use custom settings file for maven
COPY my-settings.xml /usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml

CMD ["/bin/bash"]
```

Here is the bash script that does the rest

```sh
# Provide basis for Maven local repository reuse
docker volume create --name maven-repo

# Build maven docker image with custom settings.xml
docker build --file "${WORKSPACE}"/tools/maven/Dockerfile \
             --tag my-maven-image:latest \
             "${WORKSPACE}"/tools/maven/

# Build using maven in the container
# The options -it are just there for debug purposes
docker run -it \
        --mount source=maven-repo,destination=/root/.m2 \
        --mount type=bind,source="${WORKSPACE}"/my-maven-project,destination=/usr/src/my-maven-project \
        --name maven-container my-maven-image:latest \
        --workdir /usr/src/my-maven-project
        mvn clean install
```

I expect the that `mvn clean install` is run in the `/usr/src/my-maven-project` directory of the container. Instead this directory can't be found.

I also plan to get rid of the interactive mode of the `docker run` command as soon as it works, I assume the logs of the maven command can be found in the logs of the docker container.

After a successful build I assume the artifacts will be in the same directories as if I had run the maven command from the docker host machine.